# Ember view.renderer.willDestroyElement is not a function when transition to another route from component

Tags: ember.js

In a component I setup a `PIXI.js` canvas element in `didInsertElement`.
Later when I transition to another route Ember throws this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: view.renderer.willDestroyElement is not a function(…)`

The new route appears to have loaded as the `model` and `setupController` hooks get called and the url changes to the new route. But the previous component is still loaded and the new routes DOM elements are not. Also of note the `willDestroyElement` does not get called from the old component.

I'm using "ember-cli": "2.9.1",

Updated with code snippet:

`{{game-puzzle gameType='puzzle'}}`

In the component:

```
didInsertElement() { 
    const $gameCanvas =  $('#game-canvas').get(0);

    this.set('$gameCanvas', $gameCanvas);

    this.setupCanvas();
    this.setupHud();
    this.setupPiecesArray();
    this.loadImages();
},

setupCanvas() {
    console.log('@setupCanvas');

    const width = this.get('screenPixelWidth');
    const height = this.get('screenPixelHeight');
    const $gameCanvas = this.get('$gameCanvas');

    // Use autoDetectRenderer to choose the best available renderer
    // either: WebGL or canvas
    let renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(width, height, {
      view: $gameCanvas,
      backgroundColor: 0x000000
    });

    let stage = new PIXI.Container();
    let container = new PIXI.Container();

    this.set('renderer', renderer);
    this.set('stage', stage);
    this.set('container', container);
  },
```

There is also the `gameLoop` method that uses `requestAnimationFrame` to update and render... but I dont think they will be that helpful here.

The issue seems to only happen if the canvas is initialized, with out the canvas setup the transition to route is fine. But obviously thats no good!
Which leads me to thinking its to do with the PIXI canvas setup.

Comment: can you share related piece of code?

Comment: Question updated with code snippets.

Comment: Did you override `init` method and forgot to call `this._super(...arguments)` ?.

Comment: no, not overriding init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, hold head in shame time...

After some furious debugging, I realised the conflict in naming my `Pixi.canvasRenderer` to `renderer`.

This conflicts with the Ember Container renderer (renderer._dom).

By sheer convention in `Pixi` or even in `Phaser` (seeing as Phaser uses Pixi as its rendering engine) you store the `canvasRenderer` in a `renderer` variable.

By changing `renderer` to `canvasRenderer` the error of course goes away.

```
const canvasRenderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(width, height, {
   view: $gameCanvas,
   backgroundColor: 0xffffff
});
```